# Black window on Intel XDK startup

Tags: windows-8.1, intel-xdk

I just downloaded and installed Intel XDK. When I start up the program I only see a black window. First comes a small one (the loading screen I think), then the actual program window. If I move the mouse, I can see that there are textboxes and everything (the cursor changes), but I can see nothing.
I have the latest Windows 8.1
Thanks for the help!

Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny. The path caused it. The shortcut contained a parameter, the location of the installation. That path had a whitespace in it. It was within "-s but somehow the XDK couldn't load it. Reinstalled it to an another path (simply D:\Intel\XDK) and it works now!

Comment: Which version were you running? I want to report this to engineering. BTW, what do you mean by 'It was within "-s'?

Comment: double quote mark. 0759 version (top right number in the window)

Comment: Okay, I understand, you meant that the path specified was "in double-quote marks" so spaces shouldn't have mattered, but the spaces did seem to be the problem, despite the fact that you quoted the pathname. I'll file a bug report with engineering. Thanks

Comment: p.s. I'm assuming you saw something like this:

`"C:\Users\My Name\AppData\Local\Intel\XDK\bin\nw.exe" "C:\Users\My Name\AppData\Local\Intel\XDK\xdk"`

inside the XDK shortcut that was added to your start menu?

Comment: yes it was something like that! (I installed it into "Program Files")

Answer (score 0):

Considering your latest comments, I suspect the problem was caused by some file and directory permissions issues and not the space in your path -- by installing into `Program Files` you're installing into a restricted location (read-only on Win7 and above for non-admin users). This is done on Windows to enhance the security of the system.

I'll confirm, but there may be some files that need write access in the app directory (normally `%AppData%\..\Local\Intel\XDK`). There are definitely files that get written to your local config directly (normally `%AppData%\..\Local\XDK`), but that should be placed independently of the program directory.

Comment: It is a common problem with Windows 7 and 8 that some program can only run when i "run as administrator". But I also tried that one.

Comment: I'm trying to duplicate what you experienced, but so far not much luck. :(

Answer (score 0):

Not starting the setup of Intel XDK in Windows 8.1 only I show the setup icon with written initializing.